# Initialize local variable in both branches

Tags: scala

I want to write equivalent of this Java code in Scala:

```
final Object foo;
if (/*...*/) {
   foo = /* something */;
} else {
   foo = /* something else */;
   use(foo);
}
useDifferently(foo);
```

and I am looking for equivalent in Scala. I can't let the variable uninitialized until first use (neither with `val` or `var`), so I am forced to write something like

```
val foo = if (/*...*/) {
   /* something */
} else {
   val tmp = /* something else */
   use(tmp)
   tmp
}
useDifferently(foo)
```

I find the need for temporary variable rather inelegant. Please show me the elegant way.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to write Scala code directly analogous to your Java code, but you could make this more elegant by restructuring it to achieve greater separation of concerns. At the moment, the conditional does two things: assign a value to foo and, maybe, perform a side effect. Separating these two concerns will result in code like this:

```
val conditionIsSatisfied = /*...*/

val foo = if (conditionIsSatisfied) {
  /* something */
} else {
  /* something else */
}

if (conditionIsSatisfied) {
  use(foo)
}

useDifferently(foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val foo = if (/*...*/) {
   /* something */
} else {
   /* something else */ match { case v => use(v); v}
}
useDifferently(foo)
```

Comment: This still uses a a local variable - it's just called `v` instead of `tmp`, and wrapped in a `match` expression. I'm not sure how that's any more elegant.

Comment: The expression is inlined, though, I also don't find this satisfying.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually trying to fit not java code in scala, but imperative way of development into functional. You need to write it like this:

```
val foo = if (/*...*/) {
   /* something */
} else {
   use(/* something else */)
}
useDifferently(foo)
```

And make "use()" return updated foo object.